# Multiband raster reclassify

Tags: qgis, raster, reclassify, multi-band

I have a two bands raster. I need to reclassify it following the rules "if band 1 = x and band 2 = y the new value will be 1", "if band 1 = a and band 2 = b the new value will be 2", ecc...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example use Raster Calculator:

When a condition is true, it evaluates to 1, so

when `("Virtual@1"=500)` is true and
`("Virtual@2"=200)` means `1*1*1=1`, and add more conditions with +

[image]